# Cannot find settings to change moderation options

Tags: facebook, permissions, settings

Ok- new to this today. Two major issues:

First- I am setting up a FB comments box for each of the pages on my website. I have followed step by step and have created an app so I can mederate all of the comments at once rather than page by page.  Problem is when I get to my app I am supposed to click on "settings", however I cannot find it. There is an "edit settings' but it does not take me to the box where I can choose either to make every post visible or to let me approve each comment, etc... it just takes me to a summary of my app where I can choose app display name, app namespace, etc.

Here are the directions I have been given:

Changing Moderation Settings

Click on your app in the left column. Then click on Settings (it has two small gears beside it) in the top right corner of the tool to give you access to a few options...

Second issue is that after creating my app and saving changes, I was supposed to click on "need to grant permissions" to create an access token and then see a pink box with the App ID/API Key and App Secret.

After I saved the changes for my app. there was no "need to grant permissions" nor was there a pink box. The App Id and API key and App Secret show, but they are just at the top of the app- no pink box. Do I need to do something with permissions and create an access token? If so how? (I am not even sure what this is)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the comments plugin is linked to the app correctly (which can be checked by running your URL through the [URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), you can moderate the settings in two places:

1. The [Comment moderation tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments)
2. The Settings links, with the gears, displayed in the top right **of an instance of the comments plugin itself**

You can see your current access token for an app you admin in many ways, but the easiest two places I can think of are:

1. The [Access token tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token) on the Facebook Developer site
2. By authorising your app in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)